# Referencing another interface in a interface when using lodash groupBy method in typescript

Tags: typescript, interface, lodash

I have a database model interface `User`. I want to fetch all users and store them in a key-value pair with `groupBy()` from lodash like this:

```
const users: {[_id: string]: User} = _.groupBy(await db.Users.find(), '_id');
// users = {'x': {_id: 'x', name: 'Rifat'}, 'y': {_id: 'y', name: 'Reza'}}
```

This is giving me this error `Type 'Dictionary<(Document<unknown, any, User> & Omit<User & Required<{ _id: string; }>, never>)[]>' is not assignable to type '{ [_id: string]: User; }'. 'string' index signatures are incompatible.`

Eventually I want to be able to do something like this:

```
const user = users['x']; // which should treat user as User
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loadash's `groupBy` returns an object where each property is an *array* of the items that share the group key.

So:

```
const things = [{ name: 'foo', tag: 'a' }, { name: 'bar', tag: 'a' }]
const grouped = _.groupBy(thing => thing.tag)
// { 'a': [{ name: 'foo', tag: 'a' }, { name: 'bar', tag: 'a' }] }
```

Which means you need your type to be `{ [_id: string]: User[] }` (note the `[]` to make that an array).

With that one addition, your code works just fine:

```
const users: { [_id: string]: User[] } = _.groupBy(await db.Users.find(), '_id');
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAfTgMyhEcDkAbCATAQwGcALTAKHJgE8wBTOAVSLqjgF44BvOAOwJB0AXHCIwowXgHM4AX0oBjCLzFw8AIw7dycJiyhERXHbpSS8I4tV4K4ACgCUIgApoQwFgB5mrANoBdAD4OYICTeXlyJRV4AFd9Q244XwRgC1FxSSl-ER8oALktBAA6KTRYsAAhajsCAHcCYHgNYryiYuRzRwAaLFS8TAcAbijlVXjWLQmDX0wAD0x-cgB6ZdM4AD0AfiA)

---

But, considering this is a list of users from a database, they probably all have a unique `_id`. Which means you probably don't want the `groupBy` method at all, because you do not want *groups* of users. You probably want `keyBy` instead, which returns an object where some property each array member becomes a key in the returned object.

So if you change it to `keyBy` then your original type works just fine:

```
const users: { [_id: string]: User } = _.keyBy(await db.Users.find(), '_id');
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAfTgMyhEcDkAbCATAQwGcALTAKHJgE8wBTOAVSLqjgF44BvOAOwJB0AXHCIwowXgHM4AX0oBjCLzFw8AIw7dycJiyhERXHbpSS8I4tV4K4ACgCUIgApoQwFgB5mrANoBdAD4OYICTeXlyJRV4AFd9Q244XwRgC1FxSSl-ER82WS0EADoAazpqACFqOwIAdwJgeA0ivKIi5HNHABosVLxMBwBuKOVVeNYtcYNfTAAPTH9yAHol0zgAPQB+IA)

---

Lastly, you probably don't even need an explicit type here. You let Typescript infer the type of `users` from usage, and it will also just work fine.

```
const users = _.keyBy(await db.Users.find(), '_id');
const user = users['x'] // type: User
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAfTgMyhEcDkAbCATAQwGcALTAKHJgE8wBTOAVSLqjgF44BvOAOwJB0AXHCIwowXgHM4AX0oBjCLzFw8AIw7dycJiyhERXHbpSS8I4tV4K4ACgCUIgApoQwFgB5mrANoBdAD4OYICTeXlyJRV4AFd9Ii0EADoAazpqACFqOwIAdwJgeA1knwNk5HNHABosBGA8TAcAbijlVXjWLU6DX0wAD0x-cgB6EdM4AD0AfiA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and showing the better way. `keyBy` is the perfect function for this and working great.